# Найти разницу дат C++ cli (как исправить?)

Tags: .net, c++-cli

```
starttime = gcnew DateTime(startYear,startMonth,startDay,startHour,startMin,startSec);
endtime = gcnew DateTime (finishYear,finishMonth,finishDay,finishHour,finishMin,finishSec);
TimeSpan^totalTa = endtime->Subtract(starttime);
```

Выдаёт ошибку, хотя

```
 TimeSpan^ta = endtime->Subtract(DateTime::Now); // работает
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь методу `Subtract` передать структуру по ссылке, но он ее принимает по значению, вам необходимо так сказать *разыменовать* ссылку.

```
TimeSpan totalTa = endtime->Subtract(*starttime);
```

Еще вам стоит обратить внимание на то что метод `Subtract` у структуры `DateTime` возвращает `TimeSpan`, но не `TimeSpan^`.

Comment: Error требуется выражение ( если что , у меня VS12)

Comment: Не имеет значения какая у вас VS. Вообще я так думаю что вы изначально все не правильно сделали, т.к. для структур нет необходимости вызывать `gcnew`.

Comment: убрал gcnew, ошибка не пропала

Comment: @VladNikitin: Приложите весь ваш код, и сообщение об ошибке в вопрос, отредактировав его.

Comment: @VladNikitin: Прошу прощения, разыменование ссылки делается добавлением `*` перед выражением. См исправленный ответ.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @VladNikitin - очевидно сейчас у вас в коде написано так: `DateTime ^starttime = gcnew DateTime(...);` - используется ссылка `^` и создание объекта в _куче_ с помощью `gcnew`. При этом позже нужно разыменование. Но структуру можно создавать на _стеке_: `DateTime starttime = DateTime(...);`. Тогда в методе `Subtract` разыменование не нужно.